# Binding content loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

We have a WordPress plugin, which dynamically - via AJAX calls - loads user specific content (html) to a page. However, WordPress theme and other plugin developers increasingly process(animation etc.) elements, using a combination of javascript and CSS, which exist in the DOM by `document.ready()`.

We don't have control over what they do or how they do it. If we did we'd insist on using `.on()` and `.trigger()` event delegation and packaging things up in functions.

Is there something that WE can do that ensures that all content introduced after `document.ready()` gets properly bound for clicks, animations etc?

Comment: You need to either use plugins that rely on delegated events (eg. `$element.on('click', '.selector', fn)`) or re-iniitialise any plugins on the newly appended content after each AJAX call.

Comment: Can you please try with jquery delegate function, I am not sure, but the documentaion tells it will work: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ . Yesterday I had faced similar kind of problem. When I used live method, it was fixed. But I came to know its depricated, they suggested to use delegate. Please try both and let us know wheather it worked or not .

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your jquery version, you can handle delegated events (events for elements added after the first "on" method call) with either "delegate" (for jquery < 1.7) or "on" (for jquery >= 1.7) methods.

You have to use this form, though:

```
$(".containerElement").on( 'click' , '.clickableElement', function(e){
    //Do stuff
});
```

Delegate function has the same arguments.

More info on events and event delegation on:

http://api.jquery.com/on/